# Visual Studio 2017 SSRS Report Templates

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

With the version of SQL Server Data Tools included with SQL Server 2012 you could create a report definition and copy the .rdl into the folder below and it would appear when you created a new project item.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\ReportProject

I'm trying to achieve the same with Visual Studio 2017 and the Report Project extension though this does not appear to work when I copy the file to the folder below:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\ReportProject

How can I get template report items to appear for report projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new location is now under (replace Enterprise with whatever your sku is)

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSDTRS\ProjectItems\ReportProject

**UPDATE:** This now looks to have changed to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSRS\ProjectItems\ReportProject

Comment: This is actually helpful to me right now. I didn't even know this was an option available.

Comment: Is it possible to write the reports inside vstd 2017 to work with reporting services, avoiding reporting definition errors?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the folder path has changed now that SSDT is no longer in Preview - it was released 4-10-2018 for the first complete release. Anyways, I had an SSRS template that disappeared after installing the new release. Upon inspection, I found that the folder path for SSDT templates was moved from the Enterprise to SQL paths (remove the spaces):

> **SSAS:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\SQL\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSAS\
>
> **SSIS:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\SQL\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\
>
> **SSRS:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\SQL\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSRS\ProjectItems\ReportProject\